# Efficiently assigning values to multidimensional array based on indices list on one dimension

Tags: optimization, multidimensional-array, octave

I have a matrix `M` of size `[S1, S2, S3]`.

I have another matrix `K` that serves as the indices in the first dimension that I want to assign, with size `[1, S2, S3]`.

And `V` is a `[1, S2, S3]` matrix which contains the values to be assigned correspondingly.

With for loops, this is how I did it:

```
for x2 = 1:S2
  for x3 = 1:S3
    M(K(1,x2,x3), x2, x3) = V(1, x2, x3)
  endfor % x3
endfor % x2
```

Is there a more efficient way to do this?

Visualization for 2D case:

```
M = 
  1  4  7  10
  2  5  8  11
  3  6  9  12

K = 
  2  1  3  2

V = 
  50  80  70  60

Desired = 
  1  80   7  10
 50   5   8  60
  3   6  70  12
```

Test case:

```
M = reshape(1:24, [3,4,2])
K = reshape([2,1,3,2,3,3,1,2], [1,4,2])
V = reshape(10:10:80, [1,4,2])
s = size(M)
M = assign_values(M, K, V)
M =

ans(:,:,1) =

    1   20    7   10
   10    5    8   40
    3    6   30   12

ans(:,:,2) =

   13   16   70   22
   14   17   20   80
   50   60   21   24
```

I'm looking for an efficient way to implement `assign_values` there.

Running Gelliant's answer somehow gives me this:

```
key = sub2ind(s, K, [1:s(2)])
error: sub2ind: all subscripts must be of the same size
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sub2ind` to use your individual subscripts to linear indices. These can then be used to replace them with the values in `V`.

```
M = [1  4  7  10 ;...
  2  5  8  11 ;...
  3  6  9  12];
s=size(M);
K = [2  1  3  2];
K = sub2ind(s,K,[1:s(2)])
V = [50  80  70  60];
M(K)=V;
```

You don't need `reshape` and `M=M(:)` for it to work in Matlab.

Comment: Instead of `K = sub2ind(s,K,[1:s(1)])` it must be `K = sub2ind(s,K,[1:s(2)])`,

Comment: Hmm, it says `all subscripts must be of the same size` (I'm using Octave).

Comment: @justhalf This works in Octave 4.2.0, perhaps you are using a very old version?

Answer (score 0):

I found that this works:

```
K = K(:)'+(S1*(0:numel(K)-1));
M(K) = V;
```

Perhaps this is supposed to work the same way as Gelliant's answer, but I couldn't make his answer work, somehow =/